# Autorelease used but still leaking

Tags: c++, objective-c

I am writing a C++ program that has one class that has an Objective-C++ implementation. Each function has an autorelease pool when there is any opportunity for object creation.

When a specific object function gets called more than once I get 3 log messages of the type `*** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10b730 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking`

There is an autorelease pool in this specific function and also in either of the 2 functions that can call it. Is it possible that one of the frameworks I am using is creating some global objects that get leaked ?

I tried setting a breakpoint on `__NSAutoreleaseNoPool` but it won't break. I also set NSAutoreleaseHaltOnNoPool and couldn't break either.

EDIT: Here is the code,

qtdata.h :

```
#ifndef qtdata_h
#define qtdata_h

#include "../videodata.h"

class QTData : public VideoData
{
public:
  QTData();
  ~QTData() { }; 
  bool Open(const char *seqname, QImage *img = NULL);
  bool ReadFirstFrame(const char *seqname, QImage &img);

private:
  bool getFrame(void *handle, QImage *img);
};
#endif
```

qtdata.mm :

```
#include <CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h>
#include <QuickTime/Movies.h>
#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>
#include "qtdata.h"

QTData::QTData() : VideoData(){ };

// Open and read first frame into img
bool QTData::Open(const char *seqname, QImage *img)
{
  NSAutoreleasePool *localpool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSError *error;

  QTMovie *movieHandle;
  movieHandle = [[QTMovie movieWithFile:[NSString stringWithCString:seqname
                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] error:&error] retain];

  if(movieHandle == nil)
  {
    [localpool release];
    return(false);
  }

  [movieHandle gotoBeginning];

  NSSize size = [[movieHandle attributeForKey:QTMovieNaturalSizeAttribute] sizeValue];
  width  = size.width;
  height = size.height;

  bool success = false;
  if(img)
  {
    [movieHandle gotoBeginning];
    success = getFrame(movieHandle, img);
  }

  [localpool drain];
  return(success);
}

bool QTData::getFrame(void *handle, QImage *img)
{
  bool success = false;

  NSAutoreleasePool *localpool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:QTMovieFrameImageTypeCVPixelBufferRef
                                           forKey:QTMovieFrameImageType];

  CVPixelBufferRef frame = (CVPixelBufferRef)[(QTMovie *)handle frameImageAtTime:[(QTMovie *)handle currentTime]
                                              withAttributes:attributes error:nil];

  CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(frame, 0);       

  QImage *buf;
  int r, g, b;
  char *pdata = (char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(frame);
  int stride = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(frame); 

  buf = new QImage(width, height, QImage::Format_RGB32);

  for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
      r = *(pdata+(i*4)+1);
      g = *(pdata+(i*4)+2);
      b = *(pdata+(i*4)+3);
      buf->setPixel(i, j, qRgb(r, g, b));
    }
    pdata += stride;
  }

  success = true;
  *img = *buf;

  delete buf;

  CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(frame, 0);
  CVBufferRelease(frame);

  [localpool drain];
  return(success);
}

bool QTData::ReadFirstFrame(const char *seqname, QImage &img)
{
  NSAutoreleasePool *localpool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  NSError *error = nil;
  QTMovie *movieHandle;
  movieHandle = [[QTMovie movieWithFile:[NSString stringWithCString:seqname
                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] error:&error] retain];

  if(movieHandle == nil)
  {
    [localpool drain];
    return(false);
  }

  [movieHandle gotoBeginning];
  bool success = getFrame(movieHandle, &img);

  [localpool drain];
  return(success);
}
```

Comment: valgrind should tell you if its truly leaking.

Comment: You need to show us the code.

Comment: I am using Valgrind from MacPorts on Snow Leopard; I get the beach ball continuously when the Objective-C part is reached. I'm not convinced this build of Valgrind is working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create autorelease pool for each new thread. check main.m, it create it for the main thread.

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
// your code
[pool drain];
```

read [NSAutoreleasePool doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Note: If you are creating secondary threads using the POSIX thread APIs
>   instead of NSThread objects, you cannot use Cocoa, including
>   NSAutoreleasePool, unless Cocoa is in multithreading mode. Cocoa
>   enters multithreading mode only after detaching its first NSThread
>   object. To use Cocoa on secondary POSIX threads, your application must
>   first detach at least one NSThread object, which can immediately exit.
>   You can test whether Cocoa is in multithreading mode with the NSThread
>   class method isMultiThreaded.

---

#### update:

So you have to create a NSThread object to enable Cocoa multithreading mode.

```
NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] init];
[thread start];
[thread release];
```

Than wrap all of the obj-c code in a autorelease pool like code above.

Comment: It's a C++ program: there is no main.m or main.mm; one of the classes has a C++ interface but Objective-C++ implementation.

Comment: My program is not explicitly multi threaded; it's Qt based. I tried adding the 3 lines of NSThread code you suggest to each of my public functions but still no joy.

Comment: @koan you only need to create one NSThread. If the app is single thread than try create a NSAutoreleasePool at beginning of `main` and release it at end of main.

Comment: I tried adding those 3 lines to my constructor but it didn't help. I also tried making an Objective-C function for my main to call that will start an autorelease pool; plus another function to release it at the end of main but this didn't help either.

Comment: @koan autorelease pool have to remain in a scope. i.e. you cannot alloc a pool in a function and release it in another function.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I can't add an autorelease pool to a C++ main function - I thought that was what you were suggesting to do so that the thread catches the allocations. Did I mention that my program is C++ (not Objective-C++) except for this one class ?

Comment: @koan than create a autorelease pool at beginning of each method and release it at end of method

Comment: @koan I know that QT on is using Cocoa to implement GUI which should have autorelease pool created already. And your log message is saying NSArray is leaking not other autoreleased object you created in the method. So it must happened on secondary thread. Are you sure the leaking is happening in these methods? Try comment out them and see.

Comment: The log messages appear on calling getFrame() from ReadFirstFrame(). Open() is always called when the object is constructed. If I don't use this code I don't get the log messages. I really need to find out which object is leaking but I couldn't get the debugger to break at the time of the log message.

Comment: @koan sorry can't see any problem in your code. You only use QTKit which should not leak anything. May be try step over the code and see which line cause the leak?